# odoo module data not deleted from database when i uninstall module

Tags: python, odoo-10

When i uninstalling my one module the data table is not deleted from my database. Usually all the tables and data get deleted when we uninstall any odoo module.

class section

```
class Section(models.Model):
    _name = "section.section"

    name = fields.Char(string='Section Name', required=True)
    question_ids = fields.One2many('question.question', 'section_id', copy=True)
```

class question

```
class Question(models.Model):
    _name = "question.question"

    name = fields.Char(string='Question', required=True)
    section_id = fields.Many2one('section.section', string='Section', ondelete='cascade')
```

Comment: what a question, what you want to do

Comment: i have created small odoo module with above tables but what happen when i uninstall my module it will uninstall but in database table will not drop. so when i again install that module, old  data is already present....

Comment: because the values ​​are already entered into the database. I think the easiest solutions to delete values ​​directly from your database or to create a new database

Answer (score 0):

Try this one;

Open developer mode in odoo ui. After that in Settings, click on Database Structure and Models. Search your model and delete it.

or

Create new database and install your module on that.